# Django + Auth0 "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" python 3.5.2

Tags: django, python-3.5, auth0

I know there has been a bunch of "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" question around. but i've tried and tried and no one fixes my issues.
it'll be very nice if you can help me out in my particular case.

i'm using this official example from Auth0 for django

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-django-web-app/tree/master/01-Login

I'm trying to connect django 1.11 with Auth0 and got that error on this code

```
def get_user_details(self, response):
        # Obtain JWT and the keys to validate the signature
        idToken = response.get('id_token')
        jwks = request.urlopen("https://" + self.setting('DOMAIN') + "/.well-known/jwks.json")
        issuer = "https://" + self.setting('DOMAIN') + "/"
        audience = self.setting('KEY') #CLIENT_ID
        payload = jwt.decode(idToken, jwks.read(), algorithms=['RS256'], audience=audience, issuer=issuer).decode('UTF-8')
```

i have tried to use **.encode('utf-8')** or the **b"str"** or the "rb" / "wb" but still no luck.

Thanks in advance for your help

---- edit ----

using

```
payload = jwt.decode(idToken, jwks.read().encode('utf-8'), algorithms=['RS256'], audience=audience, issuer=issuer).decode('UTF-8')
```

bring me to other error
**'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'**

Comment: Your object is apparently already bytes. Why do you want to encode it?!

Comment: Check the types of `idToken` and `audience`. They could be the variable(s) that you have to encode.

Comment: @Alasdair yes they both string. but i've encode them so they becom b'str' and the error a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' still exisit.

it looks like the only problem is with jwks.read() since if i make changes to that variable, then other type of error occur.

as RemcoGerlich mention. yes jwks.read is already an object. i've check with print() and it return <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f74d403a4e0>

i tried to see the jwks url, and it return an JSON object. so i tried to just passed that JSON object to jwt.encode() but still no luck :(

Comment: @RemcoGerlich yes apparently it's already bytes i'm just trying to encode each of that variable because i've read the solution for **"a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"** is to encode it.
i still dont know why i'm getting that error, even if all the variable is already a bytes

Answer (score 1):

jwks.read() type is 'bytes' but in jws.py the line:

> if 'keys' in key

expect list of str so to solve this convert it to list of str:

```
def get_user_details(self, response):
    # Obtain JWT and the keys to validate the signature
    idToken = response.get('id_token')
    jwks = request.urlopen("https://" + self.setting('DOMAIN') + "/.well-known/jwks.json")
    issuer = "https://" + self.setting('DOMAIN') + "/"
    audience = self.setting('KEY') #CLIENT_ID
    # convert to list str
    jws_read = bytearray(jwks.read()).decode('ascii')
    payload = jwt.decode(idToken, jws_read, algorithms=['RS256'], audience=audience, issuer=issuer)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a python 3 vs python 2 issue (the Auth0 samples seem to be written for python2.7x).

I had a similar error using the Flask example project from Auth0. To fix it, I modified the `python-jose` library. In line 222 of `jws.py` I changed 
`key = json.loads(key)` to 
`key = json.loads(key.decode('utf-8'))`. That has worked for me, I hope it works for you.

Hope this helps.

I've forked the jose package but haven't got around to putting a PR in.